# Gimp website appears to have lost its hosting

Tags: web, gimp

A cursory look to the [Gimp.org](http://gimp.org) website shows that its domain has expired. Is gimp gone?

Trying automated installers, such as [Ninite](http://ninite.com) give errors, I assume this is because its getting the same website back that I am.

Any link referring to the gimp website seems to just redirect.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't think the project died, simply they forgot to renew the domain. Just wait for official updates :)

Comment: Pity their blog appears to be one of the affected links XD

Comment: It has been fixed :)

Comment: The project is ok - it was a glitch.
Now - how this is a "programming related question" ?

Comment: @PiMan: what is our blog?

Comment: I realise it was me assuming it was something in the 'links' page, sorry about that.

Comment: BTW, what had happened: domain expiry. There are rather long grace periods after that, so there was no danger of losing it.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, GIMP is back. Alive and well.